# z-index order for draggable div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, xhtml

I want to create draggable a media player (blue box in my example) in my website and I need to put media player in front of all divs. How can i do this?

My page template is like that:

You can try it: http://jsfiddle.net/krMhY/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
    <title>Popup Test</title>


    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .contents
        {position:fixed; bottom:0; left: 0; right:0; top:100px;}

        .resizableArea
        {position:absolute; bottom:0; top:0; width:100%;}

        .resizableArea .leftSection
        {position:relative; float:left; width: 150px; height:100%;}

        .resizableArea .splitter
        {position: absolute; left: 150px; width: 4px; height: 100%;}

        .resizableArea .rightSection
        {position: relative; overflow: auto; height: 100%;}    
    </style>
  </head>
  <body                               style="z-index: 1; background-color: purple;">
    <div class="contents"             style="z-index: 2; background-color: black;">
        <div class="resizableArea"    style="z-index: 3; background-color: aqua;">
            <div class="leftSection"  style="z-index: 4; background-color: yellow;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="splitter"     style="z-index: 7; background-color: green;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="rightSection" style="z-index: 6; background-color: red;">&nbsp;<br />
                <div id="drag"        style="z-index: 8; background-color: blue; width: 100px; height: 100px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $("#drag").draggable();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing to the following will solved

```
.resizableArea .rightSection
{ overflow: auto; height: 100%;} 

#drag
{position: absolute;}
```

Comment: try `position: static;` to the `.resizableArea .rightSection`

Answer (score 19):

If none of the other elements have a defined `z-index`, using `z-index: 1` will be fine.

#### Model: How is the z-index determined?

```
                                         z-index
<div id=A>                                Auto 1
    <div id=B>                            Auto 1.1
       <div id=C style="z-index:1"></div>          Manual 1
       <div id=D></div>                   Auto 1.1.2
    </div>                                
    <div id=E></div>                      Auto 1.2
</div>
<div id=F></div>                          Auto 2
```

First, the direct child nodes of the body are walked through. Two elements are encountered: #A and #F. These are assigned a z-index of 1 and 2. This step is repeated for each (child) element in the document.

Then, the manually set `z-index` properties are checked. If two `z-index` values equal, their position in the document tree are compared.

**Your** case:

```
<div id=X style="z-index:1">          Z-index 1
    <div id=Y style="z-index:3"></div> Z-index 3
</div>
<div id=Z style="z-index:2"></div>    Z-index 2
```

You'd expect #Y to overlap #Z, because a `z-index` of 3 is clearly higher than 2. Well, you're wrong: #Y is a child of #X, with a `z-index` of 1. Two is higher than one, and thus, #Z will be shown over #X (and #Y).

The same concept can be easily visualized in this plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CCO4W0NS3XTPsVL9Bqgs?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

There is the best solution. You can't set overflow: auto.

```
.resizableArea .rightSection {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

Comment: thanks it works. but blue box still under the splitter. can i solve this?

Comment: You must insert .splitter to inside .leftSection. After, you must set the margin-left: 154px; for .rightSection.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options, take the #drag element outside the other div's and give it a higher zIndex or set the overflow on the .rightSection to visible.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The overflow: auto on the .rightSection div, is the problem. The draggable object can't (in this case) get out of his container..

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="contents"             style="z-index: 2; background-color: black;">
    <div class="resizableArea"    style="z-index: 3; background-color: aqua;">
        <div class="leftSection"  style="z-index: 4; background-color: yellow;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="splitter"     style="z-index: 7; background-color: green;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="rightSection" style="z-index: 6; background-color: red;">&nbsp;<br /></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="drag"        style="z-index: 8; background-color: blue; width: 100px; height: 100px;">&nbsp;</div>
```