# Position z-index issue in css child container front on parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone take a look http://goo.gl/X5Dzp, you see a list of data with div css.

in right side their is three icon. I want first-icon's hover hide the top border of pop-up who shown when I hover them.

Just a thing that I am able to hide the border of top of pop div when someone hover.  I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/7490193/1252580  but it's not work for me.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that your popup is **inside** the div of the icon. It is not possible for the icon to be over the div inside of it: http://jsfiddle.net/YBQfV/1/ You need to place the popup outside of the icon's div. Then it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/YBQfV/3/

Comment: did you try with the top position?

Comment: @binarious Yes, it is possible: http://jsfiddle.net/YBQfV/4/ (using `z-index: -1;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **add** the following styles to your existing ones:

```
/* any manually stacked elements need a 'position' with another value than 'static' */
div.row {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /* greater than zero */
}

div.icon.win_pop.bubbleInfo {
    z-index: auto; /* no z-index for the icon! */
}

div.popup {
    z-index: -1; /* a negative z-index for the popup */
}
```

Now the popup appears above the icon and row…

Comment: Sorry, I have tried someone other's idea who have deleted their answers. thanks for your help too.

Comment: @user1252580 Sorry for what? If it works for you, vote up and mark the answer as correct.