# z-index not working when using negative margins

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I am having an issue with z-index stacking. The below div is appearing over the top of the top div even when z-index and positions state the below div should be under the div above it.

I have provided a JSFiddle of an example with the code that I am using.

https://jsfiddle.net/6hewonhb/

```css
.above-box {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: rgba(251, 47, 111, 0.2);
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    position: relative !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.below-box {
    margin-top: -20px !important;
    margin-left: 70px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: 5 !important;
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="above-box">
    TEST
</div>

<div class="below-box">
    TEST
</div>
```

Comment: your codes are working perfectly fine...because your opacity is low its showing like this

Comment: Thank you for the help. It actually works in the fiddle but not on my website. '.below-box' is actually an image on my website and '.above-box' has some text with a link inside of it that this image is covering. Even when I change the rgba to 1, the image in below box is still covering the link.

If it helps, I am using WordPress with Visual Composer and '.below-box' is in the row below '.above-box'

Comment: Hi ALN90, unfortunately you need to create a Minimal, **Complete**, Verifiable Example. Your example is not a complete reproduction of your issue. Please copy enough code from your site to the JSFiddle to reproduce the real problem or we won't be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually working. Be careful about your RGBA values of the `.above-box` div.

The fourth value is the opacity parameter, here opacity is set to 1 :

```
background:rgba(251,47,111,1);
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hewonhb/1/)

Besides, it is not needed to add `!important;` almost everywhere in the CSS code.

**EDIT** : For your issue, please double check positions of each of these elements in the DOM before adding z-index property.
z-index property works fine with elements which are in the same level in DOM document.

[Like this example](https://jsfiddle.net/zc5pwv8d/7/)

Also, you can read this very good explanation of z-index on this post : 
[Z-Index Relative or Absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490146/z-index-relative-or-absolute)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It actually works in the fiddle but not on my website. '.below-box' is actually an image on my website and '.above-box' has some text with a link inside of it that this image is covering. Even when I change the rgba to 1, the image in below box is still covering the link.

If it helps, I am using WordPress with Visual Composer and '.below-box' is in the row below '.above-box'

Comment: Maybe update the fiddle with a more look-a-like code of your issue and I will try to fix it and explain it to you :)
You can also do a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: The fiddle will be too difficult to display because of the rows, cols, classes etc.

The screenshot of the issue: http://thenewsomeway.co.uk/zindex-problems.jpg

the text box css is: { padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; background:rgba(251,47,111,0.2); color: #fff; z-index:10!important; position:relative!important; margin-top: -200px !important; margin-right: 500px !important; margin-left: -260px !important; }

The image css is: { margin-top: -350px !important; margin-left: 70px !important; position:relative!important; z-index:5!important; }