# HTML, CSS: color not working

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website but for some reason my `color: white` is not working.

The code which is not working:

```
.main-navbar-heading-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white !important;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5rpy02er/

Comment: See the example carefully before comments like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is behind the other layer. Put z-index:

```
  z-index: 10;
```

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/5rpy02er/1/

PS: The color is working perfectly.

Comment: Arrr too fast ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Color is working fine problem is with your z-index

```
.main-navbar-heading-2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white !important;
        font-family: Raleway;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        z-index:9;
    }
```

Here is the updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5rpy02er/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just add z-index to it main-navbar-heading-2.

```
z-index:10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a further precision, you don't need to put `!important` property on `color`, it's working fine.

Like it said above, you have to add `z-index` property since the content is in `absolute` position and in the first place. By default, it's value is set to `1` and the second element has a value of `2`.

That's why you have to put a value superior or equal to `2` to make it appears in front of the other one that occupy `100%` on the `width`.

See this very good post on SO to understand more the use of the `z-index` property : 
[Z-Index Relative or Absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490146/z-index-relative-or-absolute)

Comment: I added the !important as it wasn't working so I just tested with it.And thx for the advice.