# div going under previous div instead of after

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've facing an issue which I'm sure has an easy solution yet I can't find it.

I've got two divs. The first one has a background image blurred and content inside. It works perfectly fine. But the second div instead of going after the first one goes under it.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="section1">
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>
<div class="section2">
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.section1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.section1:before {
  content: "";
  background: url('/images/background.jpg') center center;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.section2 {
  padding: 50px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #FF5D63;
}
```

I've added a margin-top in section1 for the sake of the demonstration. The result is shown in the image below :

[image]

Comment: can you tell me the exactly layout u wanna achieve?

Comment: I want the red div under the image. Like vertically under. You need to scroll to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `.section1` has fixed position and the `.section2` has static position by default, you have to specify a `relative` position for instance on the `.section2` to make it go above the first one and take the `z-index` value of 2 by default.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8oxyyd1p/1/)

I like to share this answer on SO because it explains how z-index value is counted and it's well explained : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7490187/6028607

Comment: But how to have it under it ? As in two divs following each other ?