# Jquery ui sortable reverse item.index order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

is there a way to make Jquery ui sortable have it's item index count from bottom instead of from top?

For example:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li>Item 1</li> // ui.item.index() = 0
    <li>Item 2</li> // ui.item.index() = 1
    <li>Item 3</li> // ui.item.index() = 2
    <li>Item 4</li> // ui.item.index() = 3
</ul>
```

And have it like this:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li>Item 1</li> // ui.item.index() = 3
    <li>Item 2</li> // ui.item.index() = 2
    <li>Item 3</li> // ui.item.index() = 1
    <li>Item 4</li> // ui.item.index() = 0
</ul>
```

I'm trying to set the z-index from `div.Zindex` where it's `z-index: (ui.item.index()*10)`:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $( "#sortable li" ).map( function(){
            var updateZindex = 0;
            if($(this).index() == 0){
                updateZindex = 1000;
            }else{
                updateZindex = $(this).index()*10;
            }
            $('#parent').find('div[id='+$(this).attr('id')+']').css('z-index', updateZindex);
        });
    }
});
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

Thank you

Comment: details on how your trying to use it?

Comment: sorry, I've updated with the code I'm trying to fix with the `item.index()`

Comment: Instead of trying to reverse the order, couldn't you just negate the sort position for the `z-index`? `1` would become `-10`, `2`->`-20`, etc.

Comment: @Will I can't do that because if I give negative z-index the div's hide behind everything including the `body` wich has a background image

Comment: Hmm, pretty sure there's a way to set z-index relative to these elements only. Looking that up now...

Comment: Looks like z-index is necessarily relative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482840/z-index-order-for-draggable-div/7482870#7482870

You could use negative `z-index`s if you have a parent div that has a higher index than the body. Fiddle/HTML?

Comment: Why do you need this revert? Can't you use an attribute on the li markup? Can you post a jsfiddle?